# techniques to populate fact tables in datawarehouse in SSIS

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse

I am new to data ware house and I was wondering what techniques are used to populate fact tables. From what I have read, its best to have a identity key in the fact table that increments by 1. Same goes for the dimensional tables. Just wondering if that was the case then how would you best do that in SSIS?

Comment: Also can anyone recommend a good source on the web that goes through creating a dataware house step by step with screenshots etc. Thank you

Comment: PluralSight has very good courses. You can sign up for Trial and that will let you view videos for a couple of weeks for FREE. I have full membership as I find it very useful and it is taught by best in the industry instructors. Here's the SSIS one that does detailed walkthrough of what you are trying to do - https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/ssis-basic

Comment: Does it cover aspects like populating fact tables? etc

Comment: Yes. It walks through datawarehousing using Dimension and fact tables. Also getting only "delta"s using Audit Dates and Audit Keys etc. Actually the course you are looking for is this one => https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/ssis-advanced/table-of-contents See the TOC.

Comment: No worries I'll give it ago, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `int` or `bigint` column in your SQL table with `identity(1,1)` to create an auto incrementing ID field and you can use google to find all about the different Data Warehouse techniques.

Some big names are Ralph Kimball and Bill Inmon, but there is much more info out there than anyone could reasonably summarise in the Stack Overflow format.